# Pentaho - how to get the index of selected component?

Tags: javascript, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to get the index of a selected element using `Select Component` in `CDE Dashboard`.

It's very easy:

```
SELECT id, username FROM table1      
-- this feeds the Select Component
```

I have "Value as ID" set to `FALSE`, so the dropdown will show the `username` and will return the `ID` as defined in the `Parameter` field of `Select Component`.

I need to write some JavaScript code to read both values (`ID` and `username`) from the selected option and I have tried it with `this.selectedIndex`, but it always returns `-1`.

If I can get the index, I could iterate over the `resultSet` object and get all the columns.

Also tried with JQuery, but I'm not an expert, though I gave it a try with:

```
$( "#my_select_component" ).val()
```

and it didn't work.

If there is an easier way to achieve this, I would highly appreciate it and give feedback.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your settings of the `Select Component`? Where do you place you JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this:

In PreChange of my_select_component:

```
function f(){

$("#my_select_component").on("change", function() {
    Dashboards.setParameter(
        "my_parameter_to_update_titles",
        $(this).find(":selected")[0].innerText
    );
});
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. You enriched my skills.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to obtain `id` of selected item of dropdown list:

```
function f(value) {
    Dashboards.log(value); 
    return value;
}
```

The code is placed in `Pre Change` property of my `Select Component` (note that `Pre Change` property is part of `Advanced Properties` view in `CDE`).

The `Pre Change` code is triggered before the component is changed.